# How to make Ventura run on the MacBook Air 2017?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, macbook-air, macos-ventura

Apple's [official website](https://www.apple.com/in/macos/ventura/) for macOS Ventura, under the "*See if your Mac can run macOS Ventura.*" section, states that Ventura is availible for "*MacBook Air 2018 and later*".

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air#Intel-based) for Ventura says it works on 2017 with a "*patch*", mentioning some "*OpenCore Legacy Patcher*".

What is this patcher, how does it work, and what does it do?

Comment: https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/START.html

Comment: @Tetsujin this seems to produce a fresh install of Ventura... would it be possible to _update_ to ventura in a manner that preserves everything like a normal macOS update?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea. You've got the sum of all knowledge on the subject right there, from its author.